# Embedding files via relative paths in go

Tags: go

I have this file structure:

```
lib/ 
  util.go
CHANGELOG.md
```

In `util.go` I need to embed `CHANGELOG.md`. I try:

```
//go:embed ../CHANGELOG.md
var changelog string
```

But I get this error: `pattern ../CHANGELOG.md: invalid pattern syntax`

If I can't embed resources via relative paths, what are the best practices for embedding resources in sub-modules?

Comment: `//go:embed ../../../../../../../../../../../../etc/shadow`

Comment: @zerkms yeah that doesn't work, go embed doesn't allow `..` in the path

Comment: @Andrey I think what they're trying to say is that `..` is not allowed because then any Go code you compile could access any part of your system that it wants.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

according [embed docs](https://pkg.go.dev/embed#:%7E:text=The%20patterns%20are%20interpreted%20relative%20to%20the%20package%20directory%20containing%20the%20source%20file.%20The%20path%20separator%20is%20a%20forward%20slash%2C%20even%20on%20Windows%20systems.%20Patterns%20may%20not%20contain%20%E2%80%98.%E2%80%99%20or%20%E2%80%98..%E2%80%99%20or%20empty%20path%20elements%2C%20nor%20may%20they%20begin%20or%20end%20with%20a%20slash.):

> The patterns are interpreted **relative to the package directory containing the source file**. The path separator is a forward slash, even on Windows systems. Patterns may not contain ‘.’ or ‘..’ or empty path elements, nor may they begin or end with a slash.

This means that the root of the relative path is the folder where the go sources files are located. So I think we couldn't embedding resources from other local folders.

Maybe this [comment](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/41191#issuecomment-686616556) can explain why it's designed like this, and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67357103/14075443) provide a solution.

If there is an error, please advise.